# Query for a table with big size of columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table in which there are some columns with big text data. The query for 10 rows (table has only 31 records) takes more than 20 seconds. If I remove fields with big size, the query is executed quickly. The query for 1 row (by id) always executed quickly.

How can I do the query for many rows work more faster?

The query looks like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.id), a.field_1, a.field_2, a.field_3
    , a.field_4, a.field_5, a.filed_6, ...  
FROM table_a a, table_b b 
WHERE a.field_8 = 'o'  
ORDER BY a.field_2 DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not** a function. The syntax you are using will not do a distinct on the ID column only but on all columns!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Yes, you are right! Now it more faster, but not so fast as we would like. Maybe there are something else?

Comment: Performance analysis without a query plan is mostly guesswork, please post output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE on your query after correcting the DISTINCT ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@a_horse already hinted at the likely syntax error. Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id)  a.id, a.field_1, a.field_2, a.field_3, ...
FROM   table_a a
-- JOIN table_b b ON ???
WHERE  a.field_8 = 'o'  
ORDER  BY a.id, a.field_2 DESC 
LIMIT  10;
```

Note the bold emphasis and read up on the [DISTINCT clause in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

Also, an index on `field_8` might help.
A [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(field_8, id, field_2)` might help even more, if you can narrow it down to that (and if that is the sort order you want, which I doubt).

If you want the result sorted by `a.field_2 DESC` first:
In PostgreSQL **9.1**, if `id` is the **primary key**:

```
SELECT a.id, a.field_1, a.field_2, a.field_3, ...
FROM   table_a a
-- JOIN table_b b ON ???
WHERE  a.field_8 = 'o'
GROUP  BY a.id   -- primary key takes care of all columns in table a
ORDER  BY a.field_2 DESC 
LIMIT  10;
```

Comment: As I mentioned, this works for version 9.1 (or later) where the primary key covers the whole table. You neglected to mention your version of PostgreSQL, that makes it hard to help. For earlier versions, repeat all non-aggregated columns of the `SELECT` list in the `GROUP BY` clause or use `DISTINCT ON (id)` in a subquery and apply `ORDER BY / LIMIT` in the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

why you are selecting table_b? you dont join this tables!
make a real join like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (a.id), a.field_1, a.field_2, a.field_3, a.field_4, a.field_5, a.filed_6 
FROM table_a a
INNER JOIN table_b b
    ON b.field_on_table_b = a.field_on_table_a
WHERE a.field_8 = 'o'
ORDER BY a.field_2 DESC LIMIT 10
```

then be sure that field_8 (in the where statement) is defined with a key!